# list view is not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am new to android. I am displaying list view having click event. 
When i click on any row it goes to ext activity.
I have problem when i press back button the list view is not clickable any more.
I am having the this logic under tab group. Can any one please explain how to do it?

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] data_text;
    int[] data_image;
    int k;
    MyCustomAdapter(String[] text, int[] image) {

        data_text = data_text;
        data_image = data_image;    
    }

    MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList text, ArrayList image) {

        data_text = new String[text.size()];
        data_image = new int[image.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("In adapter2");
            data_text[i] =  text.get(i).toString();
            data_image[i] = (Integer) image.get(i);
            Log.e("",data_image[i]+"");
        }
    }
      public int getCount()
      {
       return data_text.length;
      }
      public String getItem(int position)
      {
       return null;
      }
      public long getItemId(int position)
      {
       return position;
      }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
           View row;
           row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_review, parent, false);               
           TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
           ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
           textview.setText(data_text[position]);
           imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);
           return (row);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is onclick code

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v1,int position, long id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(ReviewTab.this, ReviewDetail.class);

                        View view = ReviewTabGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("com.MyITAssessment.ApplicationCodes.ReviewDetail",i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
                        ReviewTabGroup.group.replaceView(view);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Did you code anything on back press? and also post your listview click event.

Comment: make sure your listview like, listview..setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //here is your code.
   }
  });

Comment: @Hiren Dabhi Please check updated code

Comment: @RobinHood please check eddited code

Comment: Put log inside list click event and check its fire or not?

Comment: @RobinHood Yup i have to click too many times to trigger

Answer (score 1):

Seem your row view getting freeze which cause a problem, do one thing open your `row xml`(R.layout.list_item_review)

and add below line code in `main layout` of row xml.

> android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: Hey Its not still working i have put     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in main layout.list_item_review

Comment: Yeah its getting freeze, i have to scroll the list view before click event happen.

Comment: Comment listview click event code and put simple Toast or log and check whether its working or not?

Comment: I have put log into it unless i wont scroll the listview after back button is pressed the log doesn't execute. Please get me out of it.